# Removed Woocommerce Checkout Fields still required

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm removing specific Woocoomerce checkout fields, as they are not required for pick up orders.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
    unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
    unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
    return $fields;
}
```

This works great to remove the fields but doesn't allow me to checkout. I receive the following error:

[image]

I've also tried to change the **required** array item to FALSE, to no avail.

```
$fields['billing']['billing_company']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_address_2']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_city']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_country']['required'] = false;
$fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = false;
```

I'm using the Storefront theme as well as Woocommerce 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an annoying thing in Woocommerce after version 3. Either downgrade to earlier version or allow those details through especially country.  You can use css or JS to hide the form input but set the needed country in the woocommerce settings.

Comment: So it is only country that needs to have a value?!

Comment: I refactored billing_address_1 and billing_address_2 for some other details in my code but country gave me the same headache. Those three should be the issue.

Ref: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-checkout-always-appear-message-please-enter-an-address-to-continue/ and https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-enter-an-address-to-continue-2/

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem with "unset field", so just try set priority to "100" or like that 
example: add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'checkout_fields', 100);

Source:

```
if(!function_exists('checkout_fields')){
    function checkout_fields($fields){
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
        unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
        return $fields;
    }
    add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'checkout_fields', 100);
}
```